# What is the best practice for setting user service runs under when automating service deployment?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, service, automation

We are trying to automate the deployment of some of the services that we create. We don't want to hard code the user name and password into the application installer. The problem with not hardcoding usernames and logins is that it makes automation of the release problematic.

How would you go about packaging a windows service in an msi such that:

1. The service is installed to run under a particular user name, depending on the environment instance. i.e. in Production it runs under DOMAIN_NAME\ProductionServiceUser, but if we deploy the same service into staging the service runs under DOMAIN_NAME\StagingServiceUser.
2. If you uninstall the service via "Add Remove Programs", the service is removed.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically install and uninstall the service you can use the Windows Installer support:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371634(v=VS.85).aspx

Visual Studio setup projects do not support the service tables. So if you are using it, you will need to write install and uninstall custom actions which manage the service. Other setup authoring tools offer direct support for services.

To dynamically set the service account you can use a custom [installer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372432%28VS.85%29.aspx), for example SERVICE_ACCOUNT. During install you can set this property to the account you want. This can be done in multiple ways: custom actions, dialog controls, command line etc.

Services can run under a custom user account only if the [log on as a service policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx) is set for it, even if it's an Administrator account. This policy can be set during install by using [ntrights.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279664) as a custom action.

Comment: I should have been more clear. This is an unmanaged C++ service. I suppose that we could have a C# library project just to perform the service install, but there are some issues with custom actions because for some reason MS thought that it would be a good idea to have custom actions not run as the user who is performing the install.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this goes against what I suggested. If you want to use Visual Studio, the only solution is custom actions. If you don't want to use custom actions, you can't use Visual Studio (you need a different setup authoring tool which supports services).

Comment: Custom actions are fine and they are what we are using, but I'm asking more about how do you automate the deployment of the msi's if you want the service to run under a particular user account.

Comment: Basically you set the service user account from a custom action and use ntrights.exe to set the "Log on as a service" policy for that account. There's nothing more to automate. Like I mentioned, Visual Studio doesn't support this, so you can do it only manually.

Comment: I don't thing you understand. We already are doing this using custom actions, and it works fine. The problem is that we have to hard code the username and password into the installer if we want to automate having the service set up to run under a user account.

Comment: Please read my post. To dynamically set the service account you can use a custom installer property, for example SERVICE_ACCOUNT. During install you can set this property through a custom dialog. Then you can use it in your custom action to configure the service.